# How to pattern match multiple types in Scala?

Tags: scala

How to perform pattern matching for multiple types in scala ?

I am looking to achieve something like below where pattern match type of a and b and execute the code for the combination of type.

```
def equals[T](a: T, b: T) = {
    (a,b) match {
        case (a,b) : (String, String) = isEquals(a.asInstanceOf[String],b.asInstanceOf[String])
        case (a,b) : (Int, Int) = isEquals(a.asInstanceOf[Int],b.asInstanceOf[Int])  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were very close:

```
def equals[T](a: T, b: T) =
  (a, b) match {
    case (a: String, b: String) => println(s"Strings: $a $b")
    case (a: Int, b: Int)       => println(s"Ints: $a $b")
    case _                      => println("Not sure what")
  }

equals("foo", "bar") // Strings: foo bar
equals(12, 34)       // Ints: 12 34
equals(true, false)  // Not sure what
```

Comment: Thank you so much Slouc.. You saved my time.. I did not find this syntax online.. Can you recommend any website or material where can i look for Scala syntax in general in case of clarification which would save time..

Comment: No problem. Just one thing: when asking a question on SO, it is very useful to provide a [MCV example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which makes it both easier for you to reason about your problem, and for other users to answer it. For example, see how I used `println` instead of your `isEquals`; that's because `isEquals` has nothing to do with the problem itself.
  
Regarding resources, when I was starting out I liked [this book](https://www.amazon.de/Programming-Scala-3rd-Martin-Odersky/dp/0981531687) and [this course](https://www.coursera.org/learn/progfun1).

Comment: Also, when you get an answer that helped you solve your problem, established practice is to simply mark the answer as resolved. This way you're saying "yes, this is exactly what I needed", so you don't even have to write "thanks" etc. in the comments. And the person who answered it gets a sense of completion that way, along with some reputation points. That's all. Enjoy your time on SO!